# Can you give resources to Starcraft 2 ai players?

Tags: starcraft-2

Starcraft 2 ai players get resource blocked if their base structure is destroyed.  Is it possible to give them enough resources so they can rebuild it?

I've tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> but neither of these bring up the Team Resources menu when playing AI 2v2 (i.e. playing with one AI versus 2 other AIs).

Comment: I don't play much StarCraft, but your phrasing makes me curious - if you destroy a non-ai player's base and they don't have enough resources to rebuild, are they *not* blocked?

Answer (score 3):

If you're playing a single player vs the AI you cannot give them resources as you are on opposite teams.

If you're playing a custom game with another AI vs other AI then yes you can give your AI teammates resources after 5 minutes.

This is the icon you are looking for in the top right hand corner:
[image: Sharing resources with a computer AI]

Comment: Apologies for the unclear question.  I've edited it to show I meant: 'when you're playing with 1 AI versus two other AIs'.  I still haven't found if/how you can bring up the team resource menu though... could you tell me what shortcut key it is please as I can't find the "button above the minimap" that I read about elsewhere.

Comment: The button isn't above the mini-map, it's in the top right hand corner beside the resources. I'm at work right now so I can't get you a screenshot, but the button looks like two arrows that are pointing to the left and right away from each other. There are two buttons up there, but one of them is the one I am describing.

Comment: An interesting followup question would be, when an AI's Nexus is destroyed, if you give it 400 minerals, will it rebuild it and proceed normally?

Comment: The answer to the follow up question is yes, they do build it afterwards. I killed their nexus (I'm a bad teammate), waited until they were revealed (guessing the AI would build it if it had the money). Transferred 400 to them, they built a nexus.